# Angular - useFactory - Error function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function

Tags: angular, angular-factory, angular-aot, angular-compiler

I use Angular AOT compiler version 4.1.3

I have a component library that exports a factory method that is then used to provide a service:

```
export function libServiceFactory(itemId: string) {
  return (http: Http): LibService => {
    return new LibService(http, itemId);
  };
};
```

I **compile the library** with `ngc` successfully.

Then import the compiled library and I use the `LibServiceFactory` in the website's AppModule:

```
providers: [
  { provide: SERVICE_TOKEN, useFactory: libServiceFactory('foo'), deps: [Http] }
],
```

I **compile the website** with `ng build` and I get the following error:

```
ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function (position 5:10 in the
original .ts file), resolving symbol libServiceFactory in C:/Projects/MyProject/code/MyWebsite/node_modules/@mylibrary/service.factory.d.ts, res
olving symbol AppModule in C:/Projects/MyProject/code/MyWebsite/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in C:/Projects/MyProject/code/MyWebsite/src/app/app.mod
ule.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in C:/Projects/MyProject/code/MyWebsite/src/app/app.module.ts
```

The error `(position 5:10 in the original .ts file)` points to the anonymous function from the factory method: `return (http: Http): LibService => {`

As additional information, the way I create and use the factory method is the same Angular suggesting in the [official documentation regarding injection tokens](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action#injectiontoken).

Is my error the expected behavior? Or is there something wrong in my implementation?

Comment: have you found any solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot execute code inside metadata decorators (@Sth)
So you don't have the right to execute the function libServiceFactory('foo').

If you want to have a factory  (and some Service injection to get the HttpClient Service for example), 
AND in the same time give some paramtersb('foo' in your case).
You have to use the following trick:

```
export const MyLibConfig = new InjectionToken<MyConfig>('MyLibConfig');

export interface MyConfig {
  p: number;
  msg: string;
}

export function serviceFactory(myConfig: MyConfig, http: HttpClient): MyService {
  const service = new MyService(http);
  service.myConfig = myConfig;
  return service;
}
```

then you can use :

```
      providers: [
        {
          provide: MyService,
          useFactory: serviceFactory,
          deps: [MyLibConfig, HttpClient]
        },
        {
          provide: MyLibConfig,
          useValue: {p:3, msg:'foo'}
        }
      ]
```